# jQuery, string manipulation : find a tag

Tags: asp.net, jquery, dom

After a post with "`$.ajax()`", I sometimes receive an exception from the server. You can see a part of the returned HTML below:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>MyMessage</title>
  <style>
    /* ... */
  </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">  
  <span>
    <H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>
    <h2> <i>MyMessage</i> </h2>
  </span>
  <b> Exception Details: </b>System.Exception: MyMessage<br><br>
  <!-- ... -->

  [Exception: MyMessage]
    lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +159
    ...
 </body>
 </html>
```

I'd like to get the value of the title tag ("MyMessage") How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: are you looking to get the value of the title tag? In that case: `document.title`

Comment: @peirix : yes. But the content is in XMLHttpRequest.responseText

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, I don't think you can. jQuery only allows you to select tags that can be placed within a div tag. Your title tag doesn't qualify.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050333/jquery-ajax-parse-response-text/1050344#1050344) for more information.

#### Other options...

**Partial HTML**:
There are other options. You could return partial HTML whenever you experience an error. Instead of `<html><body><p>Error</p></body></html>` you return `<p>Error</p>`.

**JSON**:
You could also go with something a bit cleaner, like JSON. Since you're working with ajax anything, you could send back the following string:

```
{'status':'failed','message':'Something bad happened'}
```

And then access the 'message' value within your client-side script.

**Proxy Script**:
By using a proxy script written in either C# or PHP you can get access to the value of a title field, and return that to your jQuery ajax process.

**IFrame Method**:
Load the results up in an iframe, and then get the value through `iframe.document.title`. You can make your iframe 1x1, so it's not visible.

Comment: Other client side solution maybe ?

Comment: Go with a different type of data. Send JSON back instead.

Comment: Jonathan Sampson that's will work with this sent code (in the answer) ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170230/asp-net-mvc-with-jquery-catch-exception-display-error-message

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson : I don't decide what I return. In the ASP.NET MVC I throw an exception like this : throw new Exception("MyMesssage"); the only think I want it's the this message only to display

Comment: Look at my last suggestion, concerning the iframe.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson : not visible (1x1) and tried (display:none) but in both cases, the page behavior change :(

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson and the others :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034881/what-is-the-best-practice-for-parsing-remote-content-with-jquery/1049430#1049430

This solution works fine. It's not very "clean" but work

Thanks for your time